# javascript settimeout on Android context switch

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

In javasscript, I use setTimeout repeatedly to redraw my HTML5 canvas.

```
function doDraw() {
   drawOnCanvas();
   setTimeout(doDraw, 20);
 }
```

I have a problem on Android browser. (Perhaps on also iOS, I haven't tested yet...) :
1. Everything runs ok
2. I press the android "home" button and do someting else
3. I come back to the browser.
4. **Problem: setTimeout is not scheduled to execute again.**

So my screen refresh loop stops, and the game is "dead".

**EDIT:** Well now, I continued investigating. Turns out setTimeout still works. The real problem is that the canvas disapeard from the screen, and nothing I draw shows. The canvas is just blank.

Answer (score 1):

For rendering loops it is always advised to use `requestAnimationFrame` because it exactly knows when to schedule the callback, the best possible time slot in which browser repaint is completed.
By using `setTimeout` you will skip frames and that'll result in serious jankyy animation

and as far as question is concerned you can restart the loop on document load

window.onload = function() {doDraw();}

I hope that works .

Comment: Not good enough.... 1. requestAnimationFrame worked great on desktop, however android stock Browser does not support it on my JellyBean phone. 2. Will window.onload be called again when only switching back? I think it is called only when the page loads for the first time.

Comment: You can make use of "webkitvisibilitychange"

document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", handler);

Comment: Well now, I continued investigating. Turns out setTimeout still works. The real problem is that the canvas disapeard from the screen, and nothing I draw shows. The canvas is just blank. I will try to solve this now. (requestAnimationFrame does not work irregardless of this)

Answer (score 0):

Well now, I continued investigating. Turns out setTimeout still works. The real problem is that the canvas disapeard from the screen, and nothing I draw shows. The canvas is just blank. I will try to solve this now. (requestAnimationFrame does not work irregardless of this).

I am closing this question because I was asking the wrong question